# Rails/SQL: Using an array as a search parameter

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In an ecommerce shop application I would like to retrieve all orders that match a `first_name` that was entered via a search form and where paid == true. The search form submits the search term via params `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"john", "commit"=>"Search"}`. In the controller

```
@users = User.search(params[:search]) #returns all users with the matching first_name, e.g. 'john'
@order = Order.where('user_id = ? AND paid = ?',  @users.ids, true )
```

The query in `@order` works just fine, if only one `user` is returned, e.g. only one user is named john. But if multiple users are named John, multiple user ids are returned and the error message `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` is returned. My understanding is that the query stops working once `@users.ids is an array with more than one value.

How do I structure the following query: for each user_id return all orders (user.orders) where paid equals true.

```
Models
user.rb
has_many :orders

order.rb
belongs_to :users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to go about this.

You can use a JOIN as [Nic Nilov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38667085/479863) suggests but this can be difficult if your `@users` query is built using scopes and you don't want to manually inline those scopes.

You could also use a subquery since ActiveRecord in Rails4 is smart enough do The Right Thing when you use a relation in a `where`, you just have to use the hash form of `where`:

```
@users = User.search(params[:search])
# @users should be a User::ActiveRecord_Relation now.
@orders = Order.where(:user_id => @users, :paid => true)
```

This will end up with SQL like:

```
select *
from orders
where paid = 't'
  and user_id in (
    select id
    from users
    where /* whatever `search` does... */
)
```

The advantage here is that you don't need to know what `User.search` does as long as it is returning an ActiveRecord relation.

If your `@users` is actually an array (of `id`s or whole `User` instances) then you'd do it exactly the same way:

```
# Suppose @users is an array of Users or an array of User ids...
@orders = Order.where(:user_id => @users, :paid => true)
```

and ActiveRecord will figure out what to do with your `@users` array without you having to do anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two queries, you should use a nested query with a [WHERE IN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause

```
SELECT * from Order WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE ?) AND paid = true
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
Order.joins(:user).where(users: { name: params[:search] }, paid: true)
```

It generates a single query with an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT "orders".*
  FROM "orders"
    INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "orders"."user_id"
  WHERE "users"."name" = 'Test User' AND "orders"."paid" = 't'
```

Comment: The problem here is that you're assuming that `User.search(s)` is really `User.where(:name => s)` rather than, say, a LIKE query.